# neo4j create node with multiple object

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to create a node with multiple object like some thing below and didn't find the proper syntax for this?

```
CREATE (E:employee {
    id: 123, name: "Kamran", sal: 50000, deptno: [10, 11]
}, {
    id: 124, name: "Qutub", sal: 50000, deptno: [10, 11]
})
```

on above neo4j give below error...

```
Invalid input ',': expected whitespace, ')' or a relationship pattern (line 3, column 3 (offset: 79))"}, {"^

 Neo.ClientError.Statement.InvalidSyntax
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
UNWIND [{ id: 123, name: "Kamran", sal: 50000, deptno: [10, 11]}, { id: 124, name: "Qutub", sal: 50000, deptno: [10, 11]}] AS props
CREATE (e:Employee)
SET e=props
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this solve your problem

```
    CREATE (ee:person{name:"tahir",position:1}),
({name:"tahir",position:2})
```

Comment: This won't add the person label to the second node

Answer (score 0):

You can alter your data model so that there are separate `Employee` and `Name` nodes, as in:

```
CREATE
  (e:Employee {id: 987}),
  (e)-[:NAMED]->(:Name {id: 123, name: "Kamran", sal: 50000, deptno:[10, 11]}),
  (e)-[:NAMED]->(:Name {id: 124, name: "Qutub",  sal: 50000, deptno:[10, 11]});
```